# Several Header .h Files on Mac

Tags: macos, finder, storage, apache

[image]

I have been trying to clear out my mac, but I have hundreds of .h files that are in extremely hidden and imbedded files - I don't even know where they came from. Not only this, there can be up to 6-7 copies of the same exact document. I tried mass deleting, but I always seem to find more in my Finder.

I want to know where these files came from (why 2020?), whether it's even safe to delete these files (don't want to mess up anything on my Mac itself) and if so, how to delete all of them. I tried looking on multiple sites including here but didn't find anything that fixed my issue.

Comment: Please add the full path of some of these files, this should give some insight into how they got installed. Also, have you installed Xcode?

Comment: Also, what is the main problem you are trying to solve with this?

Answer (score 4):

These C/C++/Objective-C header files (`.h`) are likely embedded with [framework bundles](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/MacOSX/Conceptual/BPFrameworks/Concepts/FrameworkAnatomy.html). They are harmless but should not be removed.

Removing these files can break code signatures and leave your applications unable to pass macOS security checks, such as Gatekeeper.

Comment: Thanks for this. Just find them a bit annoying when trying to organize and find files.

Answer (score 3):

If you didn't manually add them, then some app that you use must have installed them. So assuming that you still have that app installed, they should be left alone.

Apps that use installers to set themselves up should be removed using an uninstaller, if available, or directions from the developer.

It's also worth noting that they are very small. Even a thousand of them would take about the same space as one song in iTunes.

Comment: That makes sense- I think it may have been because of the time I downloaded Arduino. I uninstalled the app but the header files remained.